Error in Proof Regarding Primitive Polynomials and Primes Greater Than 1398
(Iran third round) Let $P(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \dots + a_1 x + a_0$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. We call $P(x)$ primitive if $\gcd(a_n, a_{n-1}, \dots, a_1, a_0) = 1$.
Now, let $P(x)$ be a primitive polynomial of degree less than 1398, and let $S$ be the set of primes greater than 1398. We aim to prove that there exists a positive integer $m$ such that $P(m)$ is not divisible by any prime in $S$.

What I Tried:
To prove otherwise, I reasoned as follows:

Let $b$ be the product of all primes less than 1398:
$$b = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot \dots$$

Consider the polynomial $Q(m) = b m^2 + 1$, which satisfies $Q(m) \geq b + 1$ for $m \geq 1$.

Case 1: If $Q(m)$ is prime, it must be a prime greater than 1398 (since $Q(m) \geq b + 1$), which contradicts the proposition.
Case 2: If $Q(m)$ is composite, it must be divisible by at least one prime greater than 1398, since all primes dividing $b$ are less than 1398.




Question:
Clearly, my reasoning leads to a contradiction, which suggests that there is a flaw in my argument. Could someone help me identify the mistake and guide me toward the correct proof?
Thank you in advance for your insights!

Welcome to Math SE. I'm somewhat unclear about the problem statement. You use $n$ to designate the degree of the polynomial $P(x)$, but then use $n$ as the argument to the polynomial, as in $P(n)$. Are these two $n$ connected in any way? If not, I suggest using different letters. Also, is there any particular reason you chose $Q(n)=bn^2+1$, rather than just more simply $Q(n)=bn+1$?

@JohnOmielan Thanks for pointing out my mistake, I replaced all the necessary n's with m's. And, there is no particular reason I chose $Q(n) = bn^2+1$

Can you please check the exact formulation of the question. May be it was assumed that $S$ is a finite set of primes greater than $1398$?

@JyrkiLahtonen Well I check the exact formulation, it is said for all primes greater than 1398, (for reference, the question is from Iran third round 2020)

@Vivek Kalita  No, you haven't given the exact formulation of the problem, which can be found here (on p.$13$).  In the actual statement of the problem  $\ S\ $ is defined to be "a subset of primes greater than $1398$" [emphasis added by me], not the set of primes greater than $1398$. However, in the solution given on p.$44$ of document at the cited link, it is assumed that $\ S\ $ is finite, as Jyrki Lahtonen supposes. So there's actually a typo in the statement of the problem
